# Table border bug in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

If open/close tables **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/86e371de/6/)** using Firefox, unnecessary borders pop out.

[image]
I can solve this problem using JS:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $table.css({'table-layout': 'auto'})
}, 0);
setTimeout(function () {
    $table.css({'table-layout': 'fixed'});
}, 60);
```

Can it be solved without JS?

Comment: your fiddle does nothing in any browser I've tried

Comment: @JaromandaX in FF open first item and after that open/close second item

Comment: as I said, your fiddle does **nothing** in any browser I've tried - clicking all over the place, and nothing 'opens' or 'closes'

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, can you see one more time

Comment: yes, they now open and close as you wish - oh, wait, I forgot what the question was :p

Comment: I see no evidence of those phantom borders you posted in your image - which version of firefox do you have?

Comment: Issue reproduced with FF 39.0 (just updated it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem to be a bug in the graphics engine of Firefox, however I've noticed that as soon as you remove `border-collapse: collapse;` from the table, it no longer occurs.

So maybe you can adapt your styling a bit and manage to make it look good also without border-collapse. It all depends on how flexible you are on the look of the tables.